# Prices/limites of TargetingIdeaService AdWords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm interested in querying the TargetingIdeaService from AdWords, but I'm not sure if querying the service has any costs, and if "yes", what is the pricing and the limits.

I already spent a few hours looking for that info in Google and forums and even contacted AdWords support, but the guy that attended me didn't know the answer.

So, my question is: What is the pricing and what are the limits of TargetingIdeaService?

Answer (score 1):

This page says you can do up to 10,000 AdWords api operations a day for free (no cost) so long as you comply with the t&cs (otherwise there is a fee if you are non-compliant): https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/ratesheet

Comment: This is helpfull, but now I have 2 more questions. The first one: What is considered an operation? Is it the same a query with Nresults of 10 and Nresults of 100? I mean, what is the limit of key words that I can get with only 1 call to the API?  And the second question is: Is it mandatory to implement all the methods of the API or I'm just not understanding it correctly? ( https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements )

Comment: Looks like 1 GET is considered 1 operation regardless of responses.  As far as complying to the terms and conditions, sorry but you'll need to make that decision yourself!  There is a warning period so if you are in violation they warn before charging so you'd have a chance to stop.